# populating a custom boolean column in view based on record existing other table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle 10g

I have to create a view 'dposition_view' from 'dp_table' with some fields and in the end I need to have a boolean column like 'unmatched_flag'.
The value in the column should be 'true' if 'bom_mapping' table does not hold a record with matching fields in 'dp_table' and 'false' if there exists a matching record between the two tables.
The matching fields to be checked are: eng_code, work_code, position, alt_pos (common in dp_table and bom_mapping table).

How will the logic of populating this boolean flag - 'unmatched_flag' would be?

Right now I have:

```
Create or Replace view dposition_view (",,,,,"unmatched_flag") as 
(Select dp_table.eng_code,......  'UNMATCHED_FLAG' ?? )
```

Comment: Your question isn't that clear. What does _"The matching fields to be checked are..."_ mean? Are they all part of the primary key of one of your tables? What is the definition of your unmatched flag? Or, are you asking what you can use to substitute for the non-existent boolean data-type in SQL?

Comment: The matching fields to be checked mean:

Comment: The matching fields to be checked mean: if(dp_table.eng_code == bom_mapping.eng_code && dp_table.work_code == bom_mapping.eng_code and so on..) then set the unmatched_flag = 'FALSE' else set unmatched_flag = TRUE.  'unmatched_flag' is a custom column

Comment: That sure isn't valid SQL what you "have" right now. Please post the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle PL/SQL has a boolean data type, but Oracle SQL does not. I wasn't sure if you intend on storing the strings as `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` or `1` and `0`, but that's your choice. Your data structure is also not clear, but after making an assumption you may be able to outer join  `bom_mapping` to `dp_table` on your matching conditions, and then use `NVL2()` to set the desired flag in your `unmatched` column:

```
create or replace view dposition_view(
  /* Your columns */,
  unmatched_flag) 
as
select 
  /* Your columns */,
  NVL2(bom.eng_code,'FALSE','TRUE') unmatched_flag
from dp_table dp
left outer join bom_mapping bom on dp.eng_code = bom.eng_code 
  and dp.work_code = bom.work_code 
  and dp.position = bom.position
  and dp.alt_pos = bom.alt_pos
  and -- Other conditions on the bom_mapping table
where ... -- Conditions on the dp_table
```

`bom.eng_code` will be null if a match is not found by the join, and will have a value if there is a matching record. `NVL2()` can then set a desired value if matched (`FALSE`) or not matched (`TRUE`).